# Add column to a database generated with paste0 in for loop in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dataset

I have 76 dataframe (288 rows and 13 columns) called dataset_id_1, ..., dataset_id_76, generated through a for loop and a list:

```
List = list()
for (i in 1:76) {
  List[[i]] = subset(volping, id == i, select = -c(BetaCorrect, AlphaCorrect, AR, V_Ri2))
}

names(List) = paste0('dataset_id_',1:length(List))
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

After this step, I have done the additional calculation to find a parameter (alpha) for each of the 76 dataframe. Therefore, I created a list called *alpha* with length 76 and one value for each of the dataframe. Now, I want to add a column that assigns the specific parameter contained in the list to the dataframe (1, 2, 3,..., 76). However, I cannot add the column with the typical $ or [ ] because it gives me a problem. To be more clear, I have done the following:

```
n = c(1:76)
alpha = list()
beta = list()

for (i in n) {

  dataset_regr = subset(get(paste0('dataset_id_',i)), TIME >= 740 & TIME < 991)
  
  y = dataset_regr$V_Ri-dataset_regr$V_Rf
  x = dataset_regr$V_Rm-dataset_regr$V_Rf
  
  regr = lm(y~x)
  
  alpha[i] = regr$coefficients[1] 
  beta[i] = regr$coefficients[2] 
  
  (get(paste0('dataset_id_',i)))$AlphaCorrect = alpha[i] #I get an error here
    
}
```

The generated error is:

```
(get(paste0("dataset_id_", i)))$AlphaCorrect = alpha[1] : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly for this reason you should not have 76 dataframes in your global environment. It is very difficult to manage them. Use lists instead.

```
lapply(split(volping, volping$id), function(tmp) {
  y = tmp$V_Ri-tmp$V_Rf
  x = tmp$V_Rm-tmp$V_Rf
  regr = lm(y~x)
  alpha = regr$coefficients[1] 
  beta = regr$coefficients[2] 
  tmp$AlphaCorrect <- alpha
  return(tmp)
}) -> result
```

If you still want to continue having separate dataframes you could use the code that you already have.

```
names(result) = paste0('dataset_id_',1:length(result))
list2env(result, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this way, I store all the alpha values in a list (return), which is great. The unique problem is that I need to make variate the time of the data to make the regression. Basically, the user should have the ability to pick a time interval where to compute the regression. And this initially was hard for me to operate with a list (I am not an expert in R). I have tried the following for conditioning: lapply(split(volping, volping$id & volping$TIME > 840) but doesn't change the value when changing time. Thanks by the way, much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to keep data only for `TIME > 840`? You can `subset` it first before splitting. `data <- subset(volping, TIME > 840)` and then use `lapply(split(data, data$id), function(tmp) {......`